# Time complexity to add n values to an empty linked list so it is sorted?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, linked-list, time-complexity

I have *n* unsorted values as input, and an empty linked list.

Those *n* values are added to the list in such a way that at the end the list is sorted.

What is the time complexity of the most efficient algorithm for this, in the worst case?

Comment: What do you mean the worst? Once you have a solution, you can *always* do worse:)

Comment: @CorentinPane time complexity in the worst case.

Comment: Time complexity in the worst case depends on the actual algorithm you pick. Worst case complexity of the quick sort is O(n^2) for example, but I can come up with a silly algorithm working in O(n^18) as well. Do you mean "what is the **best** worst case time complexity **I can hope for**" maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually a linked list is only accessed via its *head*; there is no random access to any node. This excludes any use of binary search.

So whenever a new value needs to be added to a linked list, the starting point is always the head of the list. The only way to proceed is to follow the *next* pointer to the next node in the list until a good insertion point is found, where the new node can be inserted.

In pseudo code:

```py
insert_value_in_list(head, value):
    # create a node for the value
    node = new Node(value)

    # find out where it should be injected in the list
    prev = NIL
    node = head
    while node is not NIL and node.value < value:
        prev = node
        node = node.next

    # if there is a node that should precede...
    if prev is not NIL:
        node.next = prev.next
        prev.next = node
    else: # if there is no node that should precede, then make it the new head
        node.next = head
        head = node

    return head
```

The loop in this algorithm can take *n* iterations, where *n* is the current length of the list. This worst case happens when the inserted value is greater than all values that are already in the list.

So when inserting *n* values like that, the number of iterations of that loop can be in the worst case:

```
0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... + n-1
```

This is equal to (n-1)n/2, which is *O(n²)*. The worst case happens when the inserted values are inserted in their sorted order.

All other parts of the insertion-algorithm run in constant time, so the time complexity in the worst case is *(On²)*.

Note that the *best* case happens when the input is the reverse of the sorted order. In that case all values can be prepended to the list, and such a prepend-operation runs in constant time. Then the overall time complexity is *O(n)* -- best case.